# How do take a Paragraph and and store all sentences in a Array of String

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java. I would like to separate out all sentences of a paragraph and put it in `String[]`. My code looks like this:

```
int i =0;
if(str.length()> 40){

        int sentences = str.length() - str.replace(".","").length();
        Log.d("number of Sentences",String.valueOf(sentences));
        strlets = new String[sentences];
        for (int count =0;count<sentences;count++){

            for (;i<str.length();i++){
                char c = str.charAt(i);
                if(c == '.'){
                    break;
                }
                strlets[count] = strlets[count] + c;

            }
        }

        Log.d("strlets",strlets[1]);
    }
```

This does not give me an output I wanted. I receive only the first sentence.

Comment: try `str.split("[\\.?!,]");` to get array of statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, it can be done in one line. Namely,

```
String[] sentences = str.split("\\.\\s*");
```

which will split the input `str` on a literal `.` (and consume any following optional white-space). And, to log it you can use [`Arrays.toString(Object[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(java.lang.Object[]))

```
Log.d("sentences", Arrays.toString(sentences));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this This will split the paragraph by `.` `,`:

```
   String array[]=str.split("\\.|\\,");
```